# Formula for automatic transfer of data from one sheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula, multiple-columns, transfer

I would like to ask for help with regards to my attendance sheet.

How can I automatically transfer the data from the remarks column on Sheet 1 to the date columns on Sheet 2?

The list of subjects on Sheet 1 is not sorted so I want the transfer of data to coincide with the sorted list of subjects on Sheet 2.

**Sheet 1**
[image: screenshot]

**Sheet 2**
[image: screenshot]

This is the link of my sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y3kaOG_-xduw-Su2E4qKWNyFg70eW2qam98JwZ0vFEU/edit#gid=0

Comment: You can use an index or match function, but how are you expecting to populate the proper date from the first sheet?

Comment: I forgot to add the date sorry. There should be a date column on Sheet 1. I am quite confused on how can I formulate a formula for my sheet using index or match function. I hope you can help me . Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes I see that. Make an entry for what you're expecting to happen in your sheet and highlight it.

Comment: Sir I tried placing a formula on Sheet2! B4, what I want is that if the subject listed on Sheet 2 is the same on the subject encoded on Sheet 1 and if their dates are the same, it should register the value of remarks column on Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it to `B4` and then copy and apply to `C4:D4`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($A4:$A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP($A4:$A,FILTER(Sheet1!$A:$E,Sheet1!$B:$B=B2),COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A:$E),FALSE),)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, the formula you provided worked on the sheet.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)